# заполнение модели несколько раз Yii2

Tags: yii2

Даже не знаю как объяснить, поэтому лучше на примере:

-дана модель игра и модель скриншоты:
в форме заполняется таким образом

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'game_name')->textInput()->label('Название') ?>
<?= $form->field($screenshot, 'screensh_path')->textInput()->label('Скриншот') ?>
```

а как мне заполнять модель Скриншоты допустим два раза

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'game_name')->textInput()->label('Название') ?>
    <?= $form->field($screenshot, 'screensh_path')->textInput()->label('Скриншот1') ?>
    <?= $form->field($screenshot, 'screensh_path')->textInput()->label('Скриншот2') ?>
```

Comment: Сделать это не так просто, посмотрите такую реализацию: https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input

Comment: То что надо, спасибо огромное, буду пробовать